# printing xml as a string in the browser instead of using asXml() method

Tags: php, xml, string, simplexml

I have a simplexml object loaded with a xml string and I want to print this string in the browser. If I use the asXml() method on the object, I have to view the source of the page to view the xml script. Instead I just want to print it to the browser as a string. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the output in [`htmlspecialchars($xml);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).